# QUnit asyncTest for CORS AJAX Call always fails

Tags: qunit

I am learning QUnit Unit Testing for UI testing.

I want to test an AJAX CORS Call with asyncTest function by QUnit and following is my code,

```js
asyncTest("Async Test", 1, function () {
    $.getJSON("http://oursite.com/api/product" + "/?PageSize=' + 25 + '&ActiveOnly=' + 1   
+ '&Index=' + 0", function (data) {
        deepEqual(data, {
            status: "ok"
        });
        start();
    });
});
```

but IE Gives me following error

1.Died on test #1: Invalid character - { "description": "Invalid character", "number": -  2146827274, "stack": "SyntaxError: Invalid character at parseJSON   (http://oursite.com/scripts/json.js:532:13) at ajax (http://oursite.com/Scripts/jquery-  2.0.3.js:7276:4) at Anonymous function (http://oursite.com/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js:7447:3) at   getJSON (http://oursite.com/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js:7430:3) at Anonymous function   (http://oursite.com/scripts/custom/JSUnitTest.js:64:5) at run   (http://oursite.com/scripts/qunit.js:102:4) at Anonymous function   (http://oursite.com/scripts/qunit.js:232:5) at process (http://oursite.com/scripts/qunit.js:869:4)   at Anonymous function (http://oursite.com/scripts/qunit.js:408:5)", "toJSONString": function( a ){   [code] }, "parseJSON": function( a ){ [code] } }

PLEASE NOTE: qunit asyncTest is not even making an AJAX Call, I guess it is failing even before it does anything. It is a PARSING Error but why?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of IE?  If you are using IE9 or IE8, you are going about the the wrong way as jQuery doesn't support cross-origin ajax in IE8 or 9.  You will need to use `XDomainRequest` directly.  If you are using IE7, you are completely out of luck as CORS is not supported in IE7 at all.

Comment: You are correct Ray. I am using IE 10 and oursite.com is configured to allow CORS. IE10 gives better description of error than Chrome that just tells me                                            "Died on test #1: Unexpected token o - { "toJSONString": function( a ){ [code] }, "parseJSON": function( a ){ [code] } }"                    . But problem is still there of QUnit not even making AJAX Call due to these error(s).